# gradle evaluate if condition based on version instead of string

Tags: gradle

How can evaluate the if condition to throw an exception based on version instead of string, something like
`if(details.requested.version < 1.3.4)`

Here is the code I'm using to evaluate as a string

```
      resolutionStrategy.eachDependency{ DependencyResolveDetails details ->
               if(details.requested.group ='some group'){
                   if(details.requested.version != '1.3.4'){
                        throw new GradleException("some error")
                       }
               }
}
```

Comment: Gradle DSL scripts are either Groovy or Kotlin, and `1.3.4` isn't a valid identifier in either. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @BjørnVester I'm trying to check for log4j version defined in gradle.properties is 2.17.1 and above and fail the build if it is not